# Errors with integer division

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Trying to plot a function and so far I have come up with this.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 R = 1.097e-2
 for m in range(1,4):
     print("Series for m =",m)
     for n in range(m+1,m+6):
         invlambda = R*(1/m**2-1/n**2)
         print("  ",1/invlambda," nm")`

I'm getting errors of division by 0. Not sure why.....
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing integer divisions. Use `1.` in the definition of `invlambda`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
R = 1.097e-2
for m in range(1,4):
     print("Series for m =",m)
     for n in range(m+1,m+6):
         invlambda = R*(1./m**2-1./n**2)
         print("  ",1/invlambda," nm")
```

In python 2... the expression `1/2` is an integer division and gives `1/2=0`, therefore you have `1/2**2-1/3**2=0`. It is solved by using `1.`, i.e. `1./2 = 0.5`.

Comment: If i then wanted to plot a graph, how can i then assign these values to the x_axis without directly copying them?

Comment: What values do you want on the x-axes and what values on the y-axis?

Comment: Well the X-axis will be the results from the function and y-axis can be any arbitrary value equal for all x_values

Comment: Well, you need the data in array form, `[x1,x2,x3,...]` and `[y1,y2,...]` which you can do with `append` in a for loop. Plotting works then with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.plot([x1,...],[y1,...])`